# JFileChooser select just directories

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

I am using JFileChooser to allow the user of my application to select a directory for file storage. Per the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#DIRECTORIES_ONLY) and other StackOverflow questions I have researched I have added this bit of code:

```
fileChooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
```

Doing this does return the directory that I need, but to select that directory you have to select a *file* in that directory. If the directory is empty you have to create a file in it to select. My question is, is there a way to display only directories and to be able to select from those directories even if they have sub-directories?

Comment: Works fine for me using JDK8 on Windows 7. Only directories are display, so I can only select a directory. Start with the example from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use File Choosers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html) for more information and a working example (after you modify the code to use directories only).

Comment: Thank you, I looked over the tutorial and downloaded the sample code. I have resolved my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had AcceptAllFileFilterUsed set to false, which was causing this issue.

Comment: Go ahead and accept your this answer incase somebody has a similar problem in the future

Comment: I tried when I posted it but it says I have to wait two day. I set a reminder on my phone already.